# System.Net.WebException could not be resolved

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, twitter

While trying to use Tweetinvi in a Windows Phone App in C#, I am facing the following error :

```
Error    8    The base class or interface 'System.Net.WebException' in assembly 
'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' 
referenced by type 'TweetinCore.Exception.TwitterException' could not be resolved
```

Any hints on what could be wrong and how to fix it ?
Any more details required ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar issue while integrating the Tweetinvi API into my Windows Phone Application.
FInd the isseue posted here: http://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/workitem/1915

Inshort It seems that on Windows Phone, the System.Net.WebException does not exist.
However we can stay updated with this discussion for the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin requires .Net framework 4.0. You are using a different version.